# View WebGL Memory

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, webgl

When using Chrome Dev Tools, is there a way to view the memory allocations and deallocations for WebGL?

I would like to get a better idea of what my app does in the background and ensure everything gets cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

Try [webgl-memory](https://github.com/greggman/webgl-memory)

> This is a WebGL-Memory tracker. You add the script to your page before you initialize WebGL and then for a given context you can ask how much WebGL memory you're using.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).